# How do I know what IPs my server have?

Tags: php, ip

I am using curl and I want to randomize the IP curl used with the IPs available for my server.

I need to know the IPs available for my server. Though I can hard code it, is there a PhP program for that?

Comment: You could parse the output of `ifconfig` or `ipconfig`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are in centos, run this command using php `exec()` and it will show you all availables ip interfaces.

```
ifconfig | grep inet | awk -F 'addr:' '{ print $2} ' | awk -F ' ' '{ print $1 }'
```

Comment: I modified that into  ifconfig | grep 'inet addr:' | grep Bcast | awk -F 'addr:' '{ print $2} ' | awk -F ' ' '{ print $1 }'

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know your server's external IP address, use this function:

```
function myIp()
{
    $url="simplesniff.com/ip";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: That would give my main IP. What about the rest?

Comment: Your server may have multiple IP addresses, but PHP / cURL will only use one when performing outgoing connections. Your only other option is to use CLI tools such as Ak'ram Khane suggested. You can do that with `shell_exec()`.