# Is there a PhP function to check all available IPs in a server?

Tags: php, ip

Is there a PhP command that we can use to know all the IPs available for the server.

Basically when I uses curl I want to pick random IPs from what's available and use that IP instead.

Comment: Are you talking about local IPs on your network or remote IPs for the site you are cURLing?

Comment: Didn't you [already ask this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706902/how-do-i-know-what-ips-my-server-have)?

Comment: Yes I did. I was trying to find that one question but couldn't. Sorry. It's so difficult to find my questions. I search for PhP IP then what?

Comment: I found it in the sidebar for related questions, but you can specify your user ID and the related tags in a search which should give you what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A700663+[php]+ip